# How to test independence between multiple independent categorical data and one dependent continuous data in Python?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, python

I have data with two categorical independent variables and one continuous dependent variable. I want to check for the independence between variables. What type of test will tell me whether they are independent or not? My data looks like this:

```
gender  time      sleep_hrs
male    day        5.5
female  day        7.40
male    night      9.30
female  night      10.5
```

I have four groups here:

- male - day
- male - night
- female - day
- female - night

Comment: Are you asking about independence between variables?

Comment: @utobi Yes, exactly

Comment: You could consider a regression of sleep vs rest, possibly including also interactions. Are the measurements taken out repeatedly?

Comment: sorry, I'm new to statistics and don't understand you a little bit. would you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to handle this problem is to run a linear regression model, where `sleep_hrs` is the response and `gender` and `time` are predictors. In your case, however, your predictors are categorical variables and thus performing a linear regression model boils down to performing an ANOVA test.

Since you are interested in the joint behaviour of `gender` and `time`, the two-way [ANOVA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance) is what you are looking for. I am not very familiar with `python`, but in `R`, assuming the dataset is `mydata`, you can proceed this way.

Run

```
summary(aov(sleep_hrs ~ gender * time, data = mydata))
```

and look at the p-value (column Pr(>F)) of the row gender:time. If the p-value is low enough, say less than $0.01$ if you choose $\alpha=0.01$, then it means there is an interaction effect. That is to say, the four groups are statistically different in terms of mean `sleep_hrs`.

Then look at the rows named `gender` and `time`. The associated p-value of `gender` tells you if males have different mean `sleep_hrs` with respect to females; by the same token, the p-value associated with `time` tells you if the two `time` groups have the same mean `sleep_hrs`.

You should also take a look at the residuals of the model to make sure they satisfy the assumptions of the ANOVA test.